# How to get country specific formatting rules?

Tags: d3.js, vega-lite

I am currently building a workflow for [vega lite API](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite-api/) and want to parametrize the choice of a locale.

So I want the user to specify her country code by providing a IETF language tag like "*us-En*" or "*fr-FR*" and from that I want to obtain the country specific formatting rules (see below for the format I need).

E.g., I am looking for a function, which produces the following output for different country codes:

```
   function getLocaleFormats(countryCode) {
     if (countryCode === "de-DE") {
      return {
            "decimal": ",",
            "thousands": ".",
            "grouping": [3],
            "currency": ["€", ""],
            "dateTime": "%a %b %e %X %Y",
            "date": "%d.%m.%Y",
            "time": "%H:%M:%S",
            "periods": ["AM", "PM"],
            "days": ["Sonntag", "Montag", "Dienstag", "Mittwoch", "Donnerstag", "Freitag", "Samstag"],
            "shortDays": ["So", "Mo", "Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr", "Sa"],
            "months": ["Januar", "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"],
            "shortMonths": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mär", "Apr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dez"]
        };
     }
   }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not clear what specific problem or question is

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought it was clear: I am looking for a function which returns the formatting for any country code (I just hand coded it for "de-DE" in the above example) I thought I get it somewhere from Intl.Locale() but don't find anything

Comment: Checkout the moment locale files https://github.com/moment/moment/tree/develop/src/locale . Might help you

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be a possible source. I just thought there might be some API in the javascript language without the need for a separate library since my question seems to be applicable so broadly

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat

Comment: It also seems to just contain time formatting references (moments.js) not decimal, thourhnds and grouping formats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the references I need, they are in:

- `https://unpkg.com/d3-format@1/locale/${countryCode}.json`
- `https://unpkg.com/d3-time-format@1/locale/${countryCode}.json`

with country code being the IETF language tag like "us-En".

p.s. I noticed these formatting rules are specified in d3.js as vega lite is build upon d3.js, so I added the d3.js and vega lite tags to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the built-in [`Intl`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) object:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/NumberFormat

On instances of these objects you can call `resolvedOptions()` to get detailed information about the formatting being used on that locale.

Example:

```js
const nf = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US');
const df = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US');

const nfOptions = nf.resolvedOptions();
const dfOptions = df.resolvedOptions();

console.dir(nfOptions);
console.dir(dfOptions);
```

Comment: How do I get the format though, it applies the format to a string. How can I from Intl. obtain the formatting rule (as described in the question) e.g. for "en-US" for "thousands" or "date"?

Comment: If you need custom formats, `Intl` is not your friend. It feature common formatting for many locales, but it's configurability is somewhat limited.

Comment: To get the options that currently apply on your instance of e.g. `const f = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US');` you can use `f.resolvedOptions()` for the details. If you dig deep enough into what is available, I'm sure you can construct objects like the one you've shown.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, I was not aware of resolveOptions()